# PyTorch Lightning with Amazon SageMaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

We’re currently running using Pytorch Lightning for training outside of SageMaker. Looking to use SageMaker to leverage distributed training, checkpointing, model training optimization(training compiler) etc to accelerate training process and save costs. Whats the recommended way to migrate their PyTorch Lightning scripts to run on SageMaker?

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is specific to migration of already working code into Sagemaker, using  the [link here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/run-pytorch-lightning-and-native-pytorch-ddp-on-amazon-sagemaker-training-featuring-amazon-search/) as reference, I can try to break  the process into 3 parts :

1. Create a Pytorch Estimator - `estimator`

```
import sagemaker
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()

pytorch_estimator = PyTorch(
     entry_point='my_model.py',
    instance_type='ml.g4dn.16xlarge',
    instance_count=1,
    framework_version='1.7',
    py_version='py3',
    output_path: << s3 bucket >>,
    source_dir = <<  path for my_model.py >> ,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session)
```

2. `entry_point = "my_model.py"` - this part should be your existing Pytorch Lightning script. In the **main** method you can have something like this:

```
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
     import pytorch_lightning as pl
     trainer = pl.Trainer(
                         devices=-1, ## in order to utilize all GPUs
                         accelerator="gpu", 
                         strategy="ddp", 
                         enable_checkpointing=True, 
                         default_root_dir="/opt/ml/checkpoints",
                         )
```

3. `model=estimator.fit()`

Also , the link here explains the coding process very well .
https://vision.unipv.it/events/Bianchi_giu2021-Introduction-PyTorch-Lightning.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There's no big difference in running PyTorch Lightning and plain PyTorch scripts with SageMaker.

One caveat, however, when running distributed training jobs with `DDPPlugin`, is to set properly the `NODE_RANK` environment variable at the beginning of the script, because PyTorch Lightning knows nothing about SageMaker environment variables and relies on generic cluster variables:

```
os.environ["NODE_RANK"] = str(int(os.environ.get("CURRENT_HOST", "algo-1")[5:]) - 1)
```

or (more robust):

```
rc = json.loads(os.environ.get("SM_RESOURCE_CONFIG", "{}"))
os.environ["NODE_RANK"] = str(rc["hosts"].index(rc["current_host"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to run Pytorch Lightning on SageMaker is to use the SageMaker PyTorch estimator ([example](https://sagemaker-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aws_sagemaker_studio/frameworks/pytorch_cnn_cifar10/pytorch_cnn_cifar10.html)) to get started. Ideally you will have add a requirement.txt for installing pytorch lightning along with your source code.

Regarding distributed training Amazon SageMaker recently launched native support for running Pytorch lightning based distributed training. Please follow the below link to setup your training code

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/data-parallel-modify-sdp-pt-lightning.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/run-pytorch-lightning-and-native-pytorch-ddp-on-amazon-sagemaker-training-featuring-amazon-search/